# Supremum of norms of line integrals

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lebesgue-integral

I have the following problem:

Let's say $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded open connected set with Lipschitz boundary and $f\colon\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $f\in L^{1+\eta}(l)$ which means that
$$
\left( \int_{l} \! |f(x)|^{1+\eta} \, \mathrm{d}s \right)^{\frac{1}{1+\eta}} < \infty \, ,
$$
where $l$ is any line segment parallel to $x_2$ axis and lying in $\Omega$.

Under what relatively weak assumptions on $f$ will this be true 
$$
\sup_{l} \int_{l} \! |f(x)|^{1+\eta} \, \mathrm{d}s < \infty \, ?
$$

Comment: What assumption of $f$ do you have?

Comment: what is $x$ and $s$. The segment has measure zero  -> integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ is zero. Or shall $s$ be the Hausdorff measure? On the other hand, integrating only in one dimension, with the property $f\in L^1(l)$ one could have e.g $||f||_{[n,n+1]\times \{0\}} =n$. Hence the answer would be no

Comment: by $\int_l f(x) \mathrm{d}s$ I mean line integral of $f(x)$ over a line $l$, I thought it's common to use $\mathrm{d}s$ for that. But still, I guess my hypothesis is wrong, isn't it? What assumption of $f$ would make this work?

Comment: To respond someone's comment, you should @someone, because otherwise, he/she may not notice your response. Except some trivial condition, say $f$ is bounded on $\Omega$, I don't know what good assumption of $f$ is sufficient to imply your conclusion.

Comment: @Landscape $f$ bounded on $\Omega$ is too much. I have the same assumption on $f$ for lines parallel to $x_1$  axis but it's not still enough I guess. Anyway, thank you for your help. If this question isn't solved shall I delete somehow?

Comment: I also think it is insufficient. I don't think it is necessary to delete your question. Maybe you can edit your question to ask that under what relatively weak assumption your conclusion will be true.

Comment: Have you thought of a continuous function, that is in $L^{1+\eta}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Yes, I thought of a continuous or bounded function but unfortunately these assumptions are too strong for me.

Comment: have you then though of $H^{1+\eta}$ functions or other sobolev functions? I think you need to have so called traces on all the fine segments for the integrals to make sense. Since the line segments are Lipschitz you should be able to define object like that

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I'm not very familiar with Sobolev spaces but if it would work I will look into it. Could you explain me little more or give me a link where I could learn about it?

Comment: unfortunately I'm only familiar with some german literature on this topic, e.g. H.W. Alt - Funktionalanalysis and Chapter A6. maybe you can check the literature referred by wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space or you could check the book of adams called sobolev spaces.

Comment: An additional problem could be that traces are often defined on the boundary of a domain and not in its interior and there are theorems that say that you have a trace on each line that crosses your domain.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Thank you for helping me. I will try to solve it using the traces theorem.